# Should I reset primitive member variable in destructor?

Tags: c++

Please see following code,

```
class MyClass
{
public: 
       int i;
       MyClass()
       {
              i = 10;
       }
};

MyClass* pObj = nullptr;

int main()
{
       {
              MyClass obj;
              pObj = &obj;
       }

       while (1)
       {
              cout << pObj->i; //pObj is dangling pointer, still no crash.
              Sleep(1000);
       }      

       return 0;
}
```

obj will die once it comes out of scope. But I tested in VS 2017, I see no crash even after I use it.

Is it good practice to reset int member varialbe `i`?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161731/discussion-on-question-by-pranit-kothari-should-i-reset-primitive-member-variabl).

Comment: I recommend that you use tools such as Valgrind to spot this kind of error, rather than just checking whether "it appears to work (this time)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing a member after an object got destroyed is undefined behavior. It may *seem* like a good to set members in a destructor to a predictable and most likely unexpected value, e.g., a rather large value or a value with specific bit pattern making it easy to recognize the value in a debugger.

However, this idea is flawed and dwarved by the system:

1. All classes would need to play along and instead of concentrating on creating correct code developers would spent time (both development time as well as run-time) making pointless change.
2. Compilers happen get rather smart and can detect that changes in destructor are not needed. Since a correct program cannot detect whether the change was made they may not make the change at all. This effect is an actual issue for security applications where, e.g., a password should be erased from memory so it cannot be read (using some non-portable mean).
3. Even if the value gets set to a specific value, memory gets reused and the values get overwritten. Especially with objects on the stack it is most likely that the memory is used for something else before you see the bad value in a debugger.
4. Even when resetting values you would necessarily see a "crash": a crash is caused by something being setup to protect against something invalid. In your example you are accessing an `int` on the stack: the stack will remain accessible from a CPU point of view and at best you'd get an unexpected value. Use of unusual pointer values typically leads to a crash because the memory management system tries to access a location which isn't mapped but even that isn't guaranteed: on a busy 32 bit system pretty much all memory may be in use. That is, trying to rely on undefined behavior being detect is also futile.

Correspondingly, it is much better to use good coding practices which avoid dangling references right away and concentrate on using these. For example, I'm *always* initializing members in the *member initializer list*, even in the rare cases they end up getting changed in the body of the constructor (i.e., you'd write your constructor as `MyClass(): i() {}`).

As a debugging tool it *may* be reasonable to replace the allocation functions (ideally the allocator object but potentially the global `operator new()`/`operator delete()` and family with a version which doesn't quickly hand out released memory and instead fills the released memory with a predictable pattern. Since these actions slow down the program you'd only use this code in a debug build but it is relatively simple to implement once and easy to enable/disable centrally it may be worth the effort. In practice I don't think even such a system pays off as use of managed pointers and proper design of ownership and lifetime avoid most errors due to dangling references.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of code you gave is undefined. Partial case of undefined behaviour is working as expected, so here is nothing strange that the code works. Code can work now and it can broke anyway at any time depending of compiler version, compiler options, stack content and a moon phase.

So first and most important is to avoid dangling pointers (and all other kinds of undefined behaviour) everywhere.

What about clearing variables in destructor, I found a best practice:

1. Follow coding rules saving me from mistakes of access to unallocated or destroyed objects. I cannot describe it in a few words but rules are pretty common (see [here](https://lefticus.gitbooks.io/cpp-best-practices/content/04-Considering_Safety.html) and anywhere).
2. Analyze code by humans (code review) or by statical analyzers (like [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) or [PVS-Studio](https://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio/) or another) to avoid cases similar to one you described above.
3. Do not call `delete` manually, better use `scoped_ptr` or similar object lifetime managers. When `delete` is reasonable, I usually (usually) set pointer to nullptr after deletion to keep myself from mistakes.
4. Use pointers as rare as it possible. References are preferred.
5. When objects of my class used outside and I suspect that somebody can access it after deletion I can put signature field inside, set it to something like 0xDEAD in destructor and check at enter or every public method. Here be careful to not slow down your code to unacceptable speed.

After all of this setting `i` from your example to 0 or -1 is redundant. As for me it's not a thing you should focus your attention.